# Odd entries in Debian Linux /var/log/auth.log

Tags: linux, debian, log-files, process, var

I have found some odd entries all of the sudden in my /var/log/auth.log files.  They are showing up every 10-20 seconds or so.  There isn't anything in cron that would do this, and I am at a loss of where to look next.

```
Nov 17 02:21:06 centaur su[7498]: + ??? root:user1
Nov 17 02:21:06 centaur su[7498]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Nov 17 02:21:06 centaur su[7498]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7560]: Successful su for user1 by root
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7560]: + ??? root:user1
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7560]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7560]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7572]: Successful su for user1 by root
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7572]: + ??? root:user1
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7572]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Nov 17 02:21:22 centaur su[7572]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7635]: Successful su for user1 by root
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7635]: + ??? root:user1
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7635]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7635]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7647]: Successful su for user1 by root
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7647]: + ??? root:user1
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7647]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Nov 17 02:21:38 centaur su[7647]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
```

I was able to get information from top by using the following command, but it was less than helpful:

```
top -b -d 0.1 -n 11130 >> top-file
```

The result:

```
 6342 root      20   0 60928 1676 1260 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 su
```

Is there any way to get lsof to do something similar so I can figure out what exactly is going on?  Or is there a better way to go about this?

I tried the following command for lsof, but it didn't seem to work how I needed it:

```
lsof +r 1 >> lsof-file
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you anonimized the username to `user1`, but does it ring any bells? Is it used by any daemons/services perhaps?

Comment: what's running on the server? Any monitoring service like nagios/zabbix? Eventually you can activate debugging on the pam_unix module inside `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`